# ERRO PHP MVC, tudo tá funcionando mas fica essa mensagem de erro no site

Tags: php, html, orientação-a-objetos, mvc

Notice: Undefined index: ok in C:\xampp\htdocs\olimpiada\controller\ControleUsuario.php on line 17

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: É porque você não está enviando nada por POST na posição "ok". Para para de dar erro, você pode colocar `if(isset($_POST['ok']) && $_POST['ok'])`

Comment: SEMPRE Leia com calma a mensagem de erro. É de indice indefinido, variável indefinida "OK", em C:... na linha 17. No seu button, talvez, você não colocou o name dele como OK

Answer (score 0):

Isso é por que você não deve estar passando o índice OK por post em `$_POST`. Faça um debug na variável e veja se tudo o que precisa está sendo enviado.